# parametrising a surface

Tags: vector-analysis

I want to parametrise the surface $x^{2}+y^{2}=36$ to then calculate a surface integral however I'm not really sure how to parametrise this. Can we use $$\mathbf{r}(t) = (6\cos{t}, 6\sin{t}, 0).$$

I want to use the parametrisation to calculate the surface integral of $\phi = \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ but i'm not really sure how to find the surface normal for $S$.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = 36$ is the surface of an infinite cylinder. Are you sure you want to compute a surface integral over that?

Comment: Well the question says Let $S$ be the region of the $xy$-plane that contains the origin and is bounded by the curve $x^{2}+y^{2}=36$ and I must parametrise this surface.

Comment: It sounds like you want to find the double integral of a function over this region, instead of a surface integral.

Comment: Well then what you must parametrize is the disc of radius 6, right? Your r(t) parametrizes only its boundary

Comment: In that case, you should say "the surface on $xy$-plane bounded by the curve $x^2+y^2=36$" and you can use polar coordinates: $$[0,6]\times[0,2\pi) \ni (r,\theta)\quad\mapsto\quad (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your second comment, the surface is then a circle in the $xy$ plane, whose radius is 6.

Then a parametrization is $$\psi(r,\varphi)=(r\cos\varphi,r\sin\varphi,0) $$ where $0\le r<6$ and $0\le \varphi\le2\pi$. The surface integral is $$ \int_S\phi\circ\psi dA=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^6rdA $$ where $dA$ is $rdrd\varphi$, so $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^6r^2drd\varphi=\left.\frac{r^3}{3}\right|_0^6\cdot\left.\varphi\right|_0^{2\pi}=72\cdot2\pi=144\pi $$